# How to open Combo Box popup in javafx

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I want to show combo box popup while click or hover on any label(component) instade of combo box and I don't know how to trigger combo box popup panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`comboBox.show()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#show--)

> Requests that the ComboBox display the popup aspect of the user interface. As mentioned in the [ComboBoxBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html) class javadoc, what is actually shown when this method is called is undefined, but commonly it is some form of popup or dialog window.